# Is there a way to apply css written in a code mirror to the html contents of an iframe?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, codemirror

I have two code mirror text areas, one for html and one for css. On button press i want to output the html and css into the iframe. I.e i want to have some green text that is also bold. This will be driven by the css and html written in the text areas.

I have tried targeting the css and html attributes of the iframe which works for the html but not the css.

```
  $("#create").click(function () {
        $("#iframe").contents().find("body").html("");
        var htmlEditor = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
        var cssEditor = $('.CodeMirror')[2].CodeMirror;
        $("#iframe").contents().find("body").html(htmlEditor.getValue());
        $("#iframe").contents().find("body").css(cssEditor.getValue());
    });
```

there is also a javascript editor at position 1 in the array for the code mirrors on the page but that's another problem for another time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkI8D.jpg

as you can see from my first attempt the text comes out as bold but the bold tag isnt having the css modifications applied to it. I feel i am not understanding the iframe and how it works properly. I tried applying a class to the  tag and got no results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i have found is to append to the head the css you want to apply

```
$('#iframe').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>" + cssEditor.getValue() + "</style>"));
```

If anyone has any better solutions please do post i would be very interested!

Comment: You should also use `.empty()` to remove the contents and re-append them once an editor has been changed.